# How to fix Precision problems

Tags: c#, decimal, precision, unit-class-library, geometry-class-library

I have several classes that follow the same basic concept for dealing with units.

Here is a simple example of one being used in a unit test:

```
    [Test()]
    public void Angle_MathOperatorTest()
    {
        Angle a1 = new Angle(AngleType.Degree, 360);
        Angle a2 = new Angle(AngleType.Radian, Math.PI * 2);

        Angle addedAngle = a1 + a2;
        addedAngle.Degrees.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(720);

        Angle subtractedAngle = a1 - a2;
        subtractedAngle.Radians.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(0);
    }
```

I have made several classes like this demonstrated Angle Class, covering other basic unit types.

The specific class that revealed to me that I had a precision problem was the use of the class that handles units of length: `Dimension`

I have helped build a basic Geometry Library utilizing this Dimension class as its basic unit type. For Example, here is the Point class:

```
public class Point
{

    public Dimension X;

    public Dimension Y;

    public Dimension Z;
}
```

Lines and other shapes have properties like Length that are represented by Dimensions and endpoints that are built using this Point Class.

The problem becomes evident when I attempt to tell if those lines are all parallel. As in this function:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// checks to see whether every line is parallel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="passedLines">passed List of Lines</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool AreAllParallel(this List<Line> passedLines)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < passedLines.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!passedLines[i].IsParallelTo(passedLines[i + 1]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

It will often return false because it is checking for too high of a precision. After doing Rotations and Translations with Points and lines, the rounding adds up to just enough to make this function return false when I would like for it to return true.

So:

Which set of the following choices is the correct/better choice?

- just doing a check in functions like `IsParallelTo` for the numbers being relatively close (e.g. Within .0001 inches)

> If(Math.Abs( thing.x - thing2.x) < .0001)

- improving upon the previous idea with a variable constant that is pulled from a configuration file, therefore allowing the user to choose the desired acceptable deviation

> If(Math.Abs( thing.x - thing2.x) < Properties.AcceptedDeviationConstant)

- or reducing the problem at the root level in the Dimension Class:

I can either use the same strategy

```
//inside Dimension Equals
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return (Math.Abs(this.Inches - ((Dimension)(obj)).Inches)) < Constants.AcceptedEqualityDeviationConstant;
}
```

It would really look like this but the above is easier to understand

> return (Math.Abs(this.GetValue(this.InternalUnitType) - ((Dimension)(obj)).GetValue(this.InternalUnitType))) < Constants.AcceptedEqualityDeviationConstant;

Or finally, my last idea is to replace everything in my unit classes to the base unit of `Decimal` instead of `Double` (Dimension, Angle, Etc.) to Decimal and somehow (After studying up on it) figure out if that will help.

---

**How and where should I improve the consistency of precision in my classes' equality operations?**

p.s. The libraries are open-source and can be found (Units [here](https://bitbucket.org/Clearspan/unit-class-library) and Geometry [here](https://bitbucket.org/Clearspan/geometry-class-library))

Comment: All of the issues you're observing are due to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Which would be elegantly handled by implementing the well known pattern of: XXXXX  see [here for more details](http://media.giphy.com/media/y65VoOlimZaus/giphy.gif).?

Comment: I would advise against using decimals if you don't need that much precision.

Comment: @jth41 If I had an answer I would have submitted an answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: I would let the caller decide the level of precision required. In the IsParallelTo and AreAllParallel methods, include a tolerance parameter that gives the maximum angle allowed.

Comment: PS. Looking at the geometry library, I see a lot of redundant values in the definition of plane, line, segment and vectors. This may lead to an inconsistent state (like end points not on a line for a segment) given the precision problems. May I suggest reading on homogeneous coordinates for points and planes and for pluecker coordinates for lines.

Comment: Also you should _always_ wrap your angle values to -180° to 180°, or 0 to 360° (and 0 to π) to avoid equality comparisons failing since angles have the property of `-90°=270°`

Answer (score 0):

If `e1` is the direction of line one and `e2` the direction of line two then to check if they are parallel within a slope tolerance of θ (radians) do the following (pseudo code):

```
bool is_parallel = |Cross(e1,e2)| <= |e1|*|e2|*Cos(θ)
```

where `|v|` is the vector magnitude and `Cross()` is the vector cross product.